# "Register New File Association" for .so file type in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, .so

[image: non readable test]Please find the image attached i opened ".so" file in text editor. Please suggest which editor need to be used Android Studio.

Comment: Actually inside your JNI folder, android NDK which convert your native code like c or c++ into binary compiled code that is called "filename.so".You cannot read the binary code .so it wil create lib folder inside your libs/armeabi/ filename.so file.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the fileType you selected for .so file and then remove it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOA6P.png)